# Why doesn't NSOrderedSet inherit from NSSet?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsset, nsorderedset

Surely an ordered set is a more-specific case of a set, so why does `NSOrderedSet` inherit from `NSObject` rather than `NSSet`?

Comment: If developer.apple.com weren't down right now, I'd go take a look at the docs because now you've got me curious!  Excellent question.  And hopefully an Apple site won't stay down for too long, right?

Comment: (Disclaimer: This is pure speculation, and too unconvincing for me to want to actually provide it as an answer, but...) An `NSOrderedSet` is a more-specific case of both an `NSSet` and an `NSArray`. Those are both classes not protocols, and there's no multiple inheritance in Objective-C. So, which do you pick? There's an argument for `NSSet` because of the name, but it could totally have been `NSUniqueArray`, right? Play it safe, ditch them both...

Comment: I see exactly what you're saying, but you're right that it's not all that convincing. I'd intuitively expect `[aSet intersectsSet:anOrderedSet]` to be possible (but it's not since the `NSOrderedSet` is not a subclass of `NSSet`), so `NSSet` makes a far more logical choice for a superclass than `NSArray` - and even if they made equally logical choices, losing the polymorphism makes choosing neither an inferior option anyway.

Comment: Good question. I had to think hard about this one for a while.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I went through the interface of `NSSet` and you're right, ordered sets appear to satisfy the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and could therefor inherit from `NSSet`.

There is one little method that breaks this: `mutableCopy`. The return value of `mutableCopy` must be an `NSMutableSet`, but `NSMutableOrderedSet` should inherit from `NSOrderedSet`. You can't have both.

Let me explain with some code. First, let's look at the correct behaviour of `NSSet` and `NSMutableSet`:

```
NSSet* immutable = [NSSet set];
NSMutableSet* mutable = [immutable mutableCopy];

[mutable isKindOfClass:[NSSet class]]; // YES
[mutable isKindOfClass:[NSMutableSet class]]; // YES
```

Now, let's pretend `NSOrderedSet` inherits from `NSSet`, and `NSMutableOrderedSet` inherits from `NSOrderedSet`:

```
//Example 1
NSOrderedSet* immutable = [NSOrderedSet orderedSet];
NSMutableOrderedSet* mutable = [immutable mutableCopy];

[mutable isKindOfClass:[NSSet class]]; // YES
[mutable isKindOfClass:[NSMutableSet class]]; // NO (this is the problem)
```

What if `NSMutableOrderedSet` inherited from `NSMutableSet` instead? Then we get a different problem:

```
//Example 2
NSOrderedSet* immutable = [NSOrderedSet orderedSet];
NSMutableOrderedSet* mutable = [immutable mutableCopy];

[mutable isKindOfClass:[NSSet class]]; // YES
[mutable isKindOfClass:[NSMutableSet class]]; // YES
[mutable isKindOfClass:[NSOrderedSet class]]; // NO (this is a problem)
```

In Example 1, you wouldn't be able to pass an `NSOrderedSet` into a function expecting an `NSSet` because the behaviour is different. Basically, it's a backwards compatibility problem.

In Example 2, you can't pass an `NSMutableOrderedSet` into a function expecting an `NSOrderedSet` because the former doesn't inherit from the latter.

All of this is because `NSMutableOrderedSet` can't inherit from both `NSMutableSet` and `NSOrderedSet` because Objective-C doesn't have multiple inheritance. The way to get around this is to make protocols for `NSMutableSet` and `NSOrderedSet`, because then `NSMutableOrderedSet` can implement both protocols. I guess the Apple developers just though it was simpler without the extra protocols.

Comment: I think the protocols would make more sense - it could be more to do with the fact that the `NSMutableSet` was already defined and didn't already use a protocol for the mutability. Couldn't the protocol still be added despite the fact that `NSMutableSet` already conforms to it?

Comment: If they wanted to, they could add a new protocol without breaking anything. We might see it added in the future.

Comment: Great answer, this was used in NSHipster book, which is how I found this question... do you know why the NSHipster book links this issue directly to NSSet being a class cluster?, I simply don't see how if NSSet was a concrete class that this would be any different with the mutable copy issue, do you know? http://nshipster.com/nsorderedset/

Comment: @OscarGomez Oh cool, I didn't notice this in NSHipster. When they mention class clusters, I think they are specifically talking about how clusters (such as NSSet) often contain a mutable and immutable public class, which is the core of the problem. I don't think they're implying that private cluster subclasses affect the issue.

Comment: @TomDalling Thanks, I guess that is what he is referring to.