# Protocol bridging NSMutableSet and NSMutableOrderedSet together

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, nsmutableset, nsorderedset

In **Swift 3**, I would like to be able to create a protocol which allows me to add elements and iterate through using `for element in`. The protocol should works on both `NSMutableSet` and `NSMutableOrderedSet` (since they do not inherit from the same class).

I know there are good reasons why `NSMutableSet` and `NSMutableOrderedSet` do not inherit from the same class, it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11279208/1311272) and [here](http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/why-nsorderedset-doesnt-inherit-from-nsset-a-real%E2%80%91life-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle/).

But I want to create a protocol which only makes use of a fraction of all the methods inside `NSMutableSet` (and `NSMutableOrderedSet`).

I have gotten just the `add` to work, like this:

```
protocol MutableSet {
    func add(_ element: Any)
}

extension NSMutableSet: MutableSet {}
extension NSMutableOrderedSet: MutableSet {}

let one: NSString = "one"
let two: NSString = "two"

// Works if created with `NSMutableSet`
let mutableSet: MutableSet = NSMutableSet()

mutableSet.add(one)
mutableSet.add(two)

for element in mutableSet as! NSMutableSet {
    print(element)
}
/*
 This prints:
 one
 two
*/

// Also works if creating `NSMutableOrderedSet` instance
let mutableOrderedSet: MutableSet = NSMutableOrderedSet()
mutableOrderedSet.add(one)
mutableOrderedSet.add(two)
for element in mutableOrderedSet as! NSMutableOrderedSet {
    print(element)
}
/*
 This prints:
 one
 two
 */
```

However I would really love to be able to iterate through the elements just by using:

```
for element in mutableSet {
    print(element)
}
```

I am trying to make `protocol MutableSet` conform to the `Sequence` protocol, something like this, but it does not work:

```
protocol MutableSet: Sequence {
    func add(_ element: Any)
}

extension NSMutableSet: MutableSet {
    typealias Iterator = NSFastEnumerationIterator
    typealias Element = NSObject // I dont know what to write here
    typealias SubSequence = Slice<Set<NSObject>> // Neither here....
}

let one: NSString = "one"
let two: NSString = "two"

let mutableSet: MutableSet = NSMutableSet() // Compile Error: Protocol `MutableSet` can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
mutableSet.add(one)
mutableSet.add(two)

for element in mutableSet { // Compile Error: Using `MutableSet` as a concrete type conforming to protocol `Sequence` is not supported
    print(element)
}
```

Is it possible to make my protocol conform to `Sequence`? How should I do it? I have tried various combinations of `typealias` and `associatedtype` of `Element`, `Iterator` etc. I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38198626/1311272) it does not work for me.

**EDIT 2: Answer to my own question in EDIT 1**

I got `var count: Int { get }` to work using this solution, not sure if it is the best one though... Also would be nice to not having to implement the `var elements: [Any] { get }` in the extension of `NSMutableSet` and `NSMutableOrderedSet`, **but I guess that is inevitable?**

```
protocol MutableSet: Sequence {
    subscript(position: Int) -> Any { get }
    func add(_ element: Any)
    var count: Int { get }
    var elements: [Any] { get }
}

extension MutableSet {
    subscript(position: Int) -> Any {
        return elements[position]
    }
}

extension NSMutableSet: MutableSet {
    var elements: [Any] {
        return allObjects
    }
}
extension NSMutableOrderedSet: MutableSet {
    var elements: [Any] {
        return array
    }
}

struct AnyMutableSet<Element>: MutableSet {
    private let _add: (Any) -> ()
    private let _makeIterator: () -> AnyIterator<Element>

    private var _getElements: () -> [Any]
    private var _getCount: () -> Int

    func add(_ element: Any) { _add(element) }
    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<Element> { return _makeIterator() }

    var count: Int { return _getCount() }
    var elements: [Any] { return _getElements() }

    init<MS: MutableSet>(_ ms: MS) where MS.Iterator.Element == Element {
        _add = ms.add
        _makeIterator = { AnyIterator(ms.makeIterator()) }
        _getElements = { ms.elements }
        _getCount = { ms.count }
    }
}

let one: NSString = "one"
let two: NSString = "two"

let mutableSet: AnyMutableSet<Any>
let someCondition = true
if someCondition {
    mutableSet = AnyMutableSet(NSMutableSet())
} else {
    mutableSet = AnyMutableSet(NSMutableOrderedSet())
}
mutableSet.add(one)
mutableSet.add(two)

for i in 0..<mutableSet.count {
    print("Element[\(i)] == \(mutableSet[i])")
}

// Prints:
// Element[0] == one
// Element[1] == two
```

**EDIT 1: Follow up question**
Using the excellent answer by @rob-napier with `type erasure` technique I have extended the `protocol MutableSet` to have the `count` and also `subscript` ability, however I was only able to do so using `func` (named `getCount`) which is ugly, instead of `var`. This is what I am using:

```
protocol MutableSet: Sequence {
    subscript(position: Int) -> Any { get }
    func getCount() -> Int
    func add(_ element: Any)
    func getElements() -> [Any]
}

extension MutableSet {
    subscript(position: Int) -> Any {
        return getElements()[position]
    }
}

extension NSMutableSet: MutableSet {
    func getCount() -> Int {
        return count
    }

    func getElements() -> [Any] {
        return allObjects
    }
}
extension NSMutableOrderedSet: MutableSet {
    func getElements() -> [Any] {
        return array
    }

    func getCount() -> Int {
        return count
    }
}

struct AnyMutableSet<Element>: MutableSet {
    private var _getCount: () -> Int
    private var _getElements: () -> [Any]
    private let _add: (Any) -> ()
    private let _makeIterator: () -> AnyIterator<Element>

    func getElements() -> [Any] { return _getElements() }
    func add(_ element: Any) { _add(element) }
    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<Element> { return _makeIterator() }
    func getCount() -> Int { return _getCount() }

    init<MS: MutableSet>(_ ms: MS) where MS.Iterator.Element == Element {
        _add = ms.add
        _makeIterator = { AnyIterator(ms.makeIterator()) }
        _getElements = ms.getElements
        _getCount = ms.getCount
    }
}

let one: NSString = "one"
let two: NSString = "two"

let mutableSet: AnyMutableSet<Any>
let someCondition = true
if someCondition {
    mutableSet = AnyMutableSet(NSMutableSet())
} else {
    mutableSet = AnyMutableSet(NSMutableOrderedSet())
}
mutableSet.add(one)
mutableSet.add(two)

for i in 0..<mutableSet.getCount() {
    print("Element[\(i)] == \(mutableSet[i])")
}
// Prints:
// Element[0] == one
// Element[1] == two
```

**How can I get it to work with just `var count: Int { get }` and `var elements: [Any]` in the protocol, instead of functions?**

Comment: `_getCount = { ms.count }`

Comment: Thanks! Yes I used that, see my Edit 2, with solution just like that! Hmm... so that is the solution then? Wrapping it in a closure... (method signature)

Comment: yeah; that's a simple way to turn a property into a function. I don't understand the second question though about elements.

Comment: How can I make it possible to use subscript, in the most easy way. I got it working by adding a variable `var elements: [Any] { get }` to the protocol `MutableSet` and then the `subscript(position: Int) -> Any`. But it requires further code in extension of `NSMutableSet`: `extension NSMutableSet: MutableSet {
    var elements: [Any] {
        return allObjects
    }
}`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean this subscript to represent. Sets don't have any particular order, so you can't make a Set into a Collection indexed on Int. Subscripting is just syntax; it can mean anything you want. But if you mean "the second element of the set" that has no meaning for NSSet.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thanks a lot! :) Only makes sense for ordered set!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to almost every "how do I with a PAT (protocol with associated type)..." is "put it in a box." That box is a [type eraser](http://robnapier.net/erasure). In your case you want an `AnyMutableSet`.

```
import Foundation

// Start with your protocol
protocol MutableSet: Sequence {
    func add(_ element: Any)
}

// Now say that NSMutableSet is one. There is no step two here. Everything can be inferred.
extension NSMutableSet: MutableSet {}

// Create a type eraser for MutableSet. Note that I've gone ahead and made it generic.
// You could lock it down to just Any, but why limit yourself
struct AnyMutableSet<Element>: MutableSet {
    private let _add: (Any) -> ()
    func add(_ element: Any) { _add(element) }
    private let _makeIterator: () -> AnyIterator<Element>
    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<Element> { return _makeIterator() }
    init<MS: MutableSet>(_ ms: MS) where MS.Iterator.Element == Element {
        _add = ms.add
        _makeIterator = { AnyIterator(ms.makeIterator()) }
    }
}

// Now we can use it
let one: NSString = "one"
let two: NSString = "two"

// Wrap it in an AnyMutableSet
let mutableSet = AnyMutableSet(NSMutableSet())
mutableSet.add(one)
mutableSet.add(two)

for element in mutableSet {
    print(element)
}
```

In principle there is another way, which is to go straight to the existing " protocol which allows me to add elements and iterate through using for element in." That's two protocols: `SetAlgebra & Sequence`. In practice, I've found getting either `NSMutableSet` or `NSOrderedSet` to conform to `SetAlgebra` to be....annoying. `NSMutableSet` is basically broken in Swift 3. It accepts `Any` in various places, but is defined as being over `AnyHashable`. Basic code doesn't work:

```
let s = NSMutableSet()
let t = NSMutableSet()
s.union(t)
```

But that's because you're not supposed to use `NSMutableSet`. It's bridged automatically to `Set`, and you're supposed to use `Set` instead. And `Set` does conform to `SetAlgebra & Sequence` so that would be fine.

But then we come to `NSOrderedSet`. This is very hard to bridge into Swift (which is why the Foundation team has deferred it so long). It's really a mess of a type IMO, and every time I've tried to use it, I wound up pulling it out because it doesn't play nicely with anything. (Try to use an NSFetchedResultsController to make use of the order in an "ordered relationship.") Your best bet frankly would be to wrap it up in a struct and make that struct conform to `SetAlgebra & Sequence`.

But if you don't go that way (or just get rid of the ordered sets, like I always eventually do), then type erasure is pretty much your only tool.

Comment: you rock sir! :D Awesome! Thank you so much! I am actually using this for an extension on NSManagedObject for deep copy, similar to https://gist.github.com/advantis/7642084, but I want to minimize code dependent on if relationship is ordered :)

Comment: I wrote a follow-up question, how can I get it to work with subscript ability and with a `count` property, instead of a `func getCount()` solution? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I answered my own question (in Edit 1) with an answer in Edit 2.